# PHP / JS : prevent page from being loaded from cache

Tags: javascript, php, browser-cache

I know there are already questions with answer about this but somehow it is still not working for me.

Let's start by explaining what I'm trying to achieve.

On page A: (index.php)

```
<button onclick="openWindows()">Open Windows</button>
<script>
rand = Math.random();
window.open("http://example.com/transfer.php?transfer=secondurl.com&r="+rand);
</script>
```

On page B (transfer.php)

```
<?PHP
   header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
   header("Expires: 0");
   header("Pragma: no-cache");
   header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
   header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);

   if ($_COOKIE["redirect_count"]!="0")
        {
           $scenario = 1;
        }
   else
        {
           setCookie("redirect_count",1,time()+50000,'/');
           $scenario = 0;
        }
?>
```

The cookie redirect_count exists before reaching page B, it has 0 as default value and I can see the cookie with the right value (0) in my browser console.

Still on page B

```
<script>
scenario = <?php echo $scenario; ?>;
if (scenario == 0)
        {
            console.log('0');
            history.pushState({}, "", "http://example.com/transfer.php?transfer=secondurl.com");
            window.location = 'someurl';
       }
else
     {
        console.log('1');
     }
</script>
```

So what happens?

If I click on the button from page A, the browser opens a new tab with url from page B then go to "someurl", it sets the cookie to 1 and the back button is active thanks to the pushState instruction. If I click on the back button, it goes back to page B but scenario still have the same value (0). If after click on back, I click on reload, the value of scenario is 1. The browser did not reload page B from the server while I had specified in the PHP header that it should reload it at all times.

Am I missing something? How can I prevent the browser from retrieving this page from the cache?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: Does the browser actually reload the page at all? (or load from cache). Have you had a look at the console's network tab to see if it's actually read from cache, which would be displayed specifically?

Comment: @Seabyte no it doesn't, I don't see any network request, it's not even checking if there is a newer version of the page.

Comment: You said that you used the `History` API through `pushState`. You know that it's just a way to handle the history in your own way? This means that it won't reload anything if you don't explicitly tell it to do so on a history update (I think `popstate`, or something?) event. I could be wrong, but that's what my understanding is on this topic. Maybe have a look at [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState).

Comment: @Seabyte That might be a solution, I'll look into it. I have tried the pushstate on page sharing the same script and it worked. There must be something there too. Thanks!